# Process huge data simultaneously

Tags: spring-boot, mapreduce, cluster-computing

i have one table with a lot of data:

```
        id | title | server 1 | server 2 | server 3
        --------------------------------------------
        1  | item1 | 110.0.0.1| 110.0.0.2| 110.0.0.3
        2  | item2 | 110.0.0.4| 110.0.0.2| 110.0.0.5
        ..
        n  | itemn | 110.0.0.1| 110.0.0.2| 110.0.0.3
```

I want to process all this data using spring boot and save the result in database, so for that, what is the easiest, simplest and the best why to do that ?

It seems that the map reduce of apache can do this job but it is so big and complicated to set up.

**The actual use case:**

1. one spring boot instance
2. select * from item;
3. process item by item.

**The expected use case:**

1. n spring boot instance
2. select * from item limit n
3. process item by item
4. consolidation of result and save in database

Comment: I have added a possible design. Kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Spring Batch. It allows chunking (processing the data in multiple chunks in multiple threads) and should fit your use case very well.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/spring-batch-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

What I may suggest is to have one data processing pipeline setup using Spring Batch rather than n spring boot instances.

Spring batch will have each of the steps as below:

1. Extract Data using Hive (select * from item) - Make sure to write them as file output to an external location.
2. The extracted data is the input to a MapReduce framework, where **each item** is processed and desired output is written.
3. The output of the mapreduce is consolidated in this batch step.
4. Another process (again distributed, if possible) to save into database.

Comment: i think the best solution is not to use all existing framework (spring batch,hive and mapreduce) to do a simple functionality, also you add a layer write data to a separate file wish add other problem of disk availability.